# Is there a possibility to get the number of displays in Python without any external modules?

Tags: python, linux, windows, user-interface, tkinter

I am writing an application in Python using Tkinter, that will be used under both Linux and Windows.

For the correct positioning and scaling of the GUI, i need to know the number of displays connected.

I found some solutions on Google, but they all require external modules like gtk, Xlib etc. I want to get it with a native python solution, if possible, so it won't be necessary to install more than python itself, matplotlib and numpy.

Any suggestions about this?

Comment: On systems running X windows, you can get a list of displays from `/tmp/.X11-unix`. Note that Tkinter isn't always bundled with Python, so some of your users may need to install it.

Comment: How do i get that list? On my unix system, in /tmp/.X11-unix theres only one file ( X0 ) i got no permissions to access. 
I am aware of the need to install Tkinter, i made sure it's installed on all devices my application will be used on. Nevertheless, thank you.

Comment: That file's actually a socket. `X0` means that X has a single display, `:0`. Take a look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196677/what-is-tmp-x11-unix

Comment: But i got two displays?